# WinUI 3 crash issue when Progress Ring Initiliazes in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: winui-3

**Edit 3: Complete project if anybody wants to check**

https://github.com/sumnoon/ProgressRingSample_WinUI3

**Edit 2: Added Complete code**

**Edit: Added the code I am trying to use as sample**

I am trying to add progress ring in WinUI 3 sample app. The plan is simple, add a button and when clicked show a progress ring.

I have intialized the progress ring similar to this. This is the XAML code for ProgressRingControl.xaml,

```
<UserControl
x:Class="progress_sample.ProgressRingControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:progress_sample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

    <Grid x:Name="IndeterminateProgressPanel"
        Background="LightGray"
        Opacity=".5">
    </Grid>

    <ProgressRing x:Name="IndeterminateProgress"
                  Foreground="Red"
                  Width="65"
                  Height="65" />
</Grid>
```

And this the code for ProgressRingControl.xaml.cs,

```
    using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
    using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
    using Windows.UI.Core;

namespace progress_sample
{
    public sealed partial class ProgressRingControl : UserControl
    {
        private Popup popup = null;
        public ProgressRingControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += ProgressRingControl_BackRequested;
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.SizeChanged += CoreWindow_SizeChanged;

            popup = new Popup
            {
                Child = this
            };
        }

        public static ProgressRingControl Instance
        {
            get { return Singleton<ProgressRingControl>.Instance; }
        }

        private void CoreWindow_SizeChanged(CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            UpdateUI();
        }

        private void UpdateUI()
        {
            var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
            this.Width = bounds.Width;
            this.Height = bounds.Height;
        }

        private void ProgressRingControl_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            //HideProgressRing();
        }
        public void ShowProgressRing()
        {
            IndeterminateProgress.IsActive = true;
            popup.IsOpen = true;
            UpdateUI();
        }

        public void HideProgressRing()
        {
            if (popup.IsOpen)
            {
                IndeterminateProgress.IsActive = false;
                popup.IsOpen = false;
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested -= ProgressRingControl_BackRequested;
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.SizeChanged -= CoreWindow_SizeChanged;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I am calling this From MainWindow.xaml using a button in such a way that when button is clicked the progress ring should show for 1000ms than hide. I have added MainWindow.xaml and MainWindows.xaml.cs code also,
MainWindow.xaml code:**

```
    <Window
    x:Class="progress_sample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:progress_sample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**And MainWindow.xaml.cs code is given below,**

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace progress_sample
{

    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProgressRingControl.Instance.ShowProgressRing();
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            ProgressRingControl.Instance.HideProgressRing();
        }
    }
}
```

But during initialization of ProgressRingControl, it is crashing and gives this error,

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Any help?

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest WinUI3 (1.1.5 as of today)

Comment: Sorry, I have updated but still crashing.

Comment: You should post a full reproducible project: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier I have added a full reproducible example. Hope this can be used for reproduction. Thank you for your suggestion btw.

Comment: This is not a fully reproducible example, it's far from compiling, and there's this Singleton thing that is a bad smell. You should not use singletons for Xaml windows, controls, UI elements, etc. Just create one when you need one.

Comment: Hi @SimonMourier I have added complete project link in my post with edit. I think it should satisfy your query.

Comment: SystemNavigationManager & Window.Current are only available in UWP, not in WinUI3 see this for some more background https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4174  .In fact Window.Current being null is a sign that you're not in UWP somehow, and most GetForCurrentView methods - for almost any type - don't work outside of UWP.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the easiest way that I can think of.

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="ProgressRingTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <ToggleButton
            x:Name="ToggleButtonControl"
            Checked="ToggleButtonControl_Changed"
            Content="Toggle Button"
            Unchecked="ToggleButtonControl_Changed" />
        <ProgressRing
            x:Name="ProgressRingControl"
            IsIndeterminate="False" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace ProgressRingTest;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ToggleButtonControl_Changed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ProgressRingControl.IsIndeterminate = this.ToggleButtonControl.IsChecked ?? false;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is another way to do to achieve what you said in your comments.
In this case, I'm creating an `UserControl`. I'm also using the **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm** NuGet package to demonstrate a way to run a process in the back.

**PopupWithProgressRing.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PopupTest;

public sealed partial class PopupWithProgressRing : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(IsOpen),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(PopupWithProgressRing),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsOpenPropertyChanged));

    public PopupWithProgressRing()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsOpenProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value);
    }

    private static async void OnIsOpenPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is PopupWithProgressRing self &&
            e.NewValue is bool value)
        {
            // The ProgressRing won't freezes in the 2nd run without this delay.
            // Probably a WinUI 3 bug. I'll report to the WinUI 3 later.
            await Task.Delay(100);
            self.ProgressRingControl.IsIndeterminate = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**PopupWithProgressRing.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="PopupTest.PopupWithProgressRing"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:PopupTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Popup
            x:Name="ProgressRingPopup"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            IsOpen="{x:Bind IsOpen, Mode=OneWay}">
            <StackPanel>
                <ProgressRing x:Name="ProgressRingControl" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PopupTest;

public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [RelayCommand]
    // The CommunityToolkit.Mvvm will automatically generate
    // a "RunProcessCommand" for you.
    private async Task RunProcess()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace PopupTest;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="PopupTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:PopupTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton
            Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.RunProcessCommand}"
            Content="Run process" />

        <local:PopupWithProgressRing
            x:Name="ProgressRingPopup"
            IsOpen="{x:Bind ViewModel.RunProcessCommand.IsRunning, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew, I am sorry that I couldn't properly convey my question in the first iteration of my post. I have edited now. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi @Sumnoon. I saw your code but IMHO you need to reconsider a lot in your design. I'm assuming that some process (1 sec) runs when you click a button and you want to show a ``Popup`` with a ``ProgressRing`` while this process is running, then you want to close this ``Popup`` when the process. Am I correct? And this process, of course, is outside your ``ProgressRingControl``?

Comment: Hi @Andrew. Yes you are correct. BTW, I have shared the complete sample code link that I have used for reproduction. You can check that too if you want. However the crash issue occurs due to SystemNavigationManager & Window.Current not supported in WinUI 3. Is there any alternate for this in regard of my case?

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if you have any questions.